# Session timeout alert with showmodaldialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

My application has session timout functionality. The popup is shown whenever session timeout occurs.The application has modal dialogs for various operations. If the user is not opened any popup then the session timeout window shows without any issue. If the user is in popup window then session timeout window runs behind the popup.

My session timeout alert has

widow.focus();

But still it appears behind the popup. Is there any to bring in-front of the modal popup?

Comment: You should provide code on how you open this session timeout window

Comment: Close any modal popups before showing the timeout message

Comment: @mplungjan thank you, i can't close the window if the user is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on information, how your code works.

But maybe there is simple issue:
When you are creating timeout dialog, lets give him huge `z-index` value.

For example:

```
#timeoutDialog {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Standard dialogs are using z-index 100+, sometimes more. If 1000 will not work, try bigger value.